# three js change background image on function call

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, rendering

**PREMISE:**

I'm trying to create a static scene that has a fixed image background and a geometry in front of it. Since the scene is static, I don't need and `envMap`.

I created two scenes and cameras (one for the background and one for the geometries) as suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865537/three-js-set-background-image), and [this demo](http://jeremy.assenat.free.fr/Lab/threejsbg/), and updated the procedure to consider that [THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087757/three-js-and-loading-a-cross-domain-image/37325781#37325781). Here is the working code:

```
// load the background texture
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
texture = loader.load('path_to_image.jpg');
var backgroundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2, 0),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture
    })
);
backgroundMesh.material.depthTest = false;
backgroundMesh.material.depthWrite = false;

// create your background scene
backgroundScene = new THREE.Scene();
backgroundCamera = new THREE.Camera();
backgroundScene.add( backgroundCamera );
backgroundScene.add( backgroundMesh );
```

The variables `backgroundScene` and `backgroundCamera` are global and the following procedure is called inside the `init()` function. All scenes and cameras are later rendered using:

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
renderer.clear();
renderer.render( backgroundScene , backgroundCamera);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

**PROBLEM:**

I implemented an event listener that is supposed to change the background image and geometry when a button is pressed, however this is not working.

I thought that loading the new texture and changing the material property of the `backgroundScene` variable, clearing the `renderer` and rendering the scene again would do the job. Here is the code:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load('path_to_new_image.jpg');
console.debug(texture);
console.debug(backgroundScene.children[1].material.map);
backgroundScene.children[1].material.map = texture;
console.debug(backgroundScene.children[1].material.map);

renderer.clear();
renderer.render( backgroundScene , backgroundCamera );
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

The `console.debug()` show me that the new texture is actually loaded and the `backgroundScene` material is changed accordingly.

However, while the geometries are rendered fine I am left with a blank background and get the following error: `[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x364ad7e56700]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0`.

Any ideas of what is going on? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you will need to call `object.material.needsUpdate = true;` for the change to take effect (see [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things)). When the `map`-property of the material is changed, three.js needs to re-setup the texture-binding, which is skipped unless the `needsUpdate`-flag is set.

Alternatively, if you just change the `material.map.image`-property it should work without that extra-step.