# how to get Sun Rays from the middle of the object in threejs

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have an object where random open particles and others are solid. How do i place a fake sun inside of the object and get Rays through the open particles using threejs. When the object rotate either X,Y Rays should spreed through the open particles ( POST PROCESSING ) ?

[SAMPLE VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suqFV7VGsL4)

My Object three.Js code is bellow

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

   init();
   animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 200;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0.6 );
  scene.add(hemiLight);

  var geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry(80, 0);

  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    specular: 0xffffff,
    shininess: 1,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: 1,
    wireframe:true

  });

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(mesh);

  var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( mesh.geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry
  var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 } );
  var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
  mesh.add( wireframe );

  //outer frame end

  //inner world like object start

  var sphere_material = [
      new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { transparent: true, opacity: 0 } )
  ];

  var sphere_geometry = new THREE.OctahedronGeometry( 60, 3 );
  // assign material to each face
  for( var i = 0; i < sphere_geometry.faces.length; i++ ) {
      sphere_geometry.faces[ i ].materialIndex = THREE.Math.randInt( 0, 1 );
  }

  sphere_geometry.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();

  var sphere_mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere_geometry, sphere_material );
  sphere_mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0)
  mesh.add(sphere_mesh);


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}
renderer.gammaInput = true;
renderer.gammaOutput = true;

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  mesh.rotation.x += 0.003;
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.003;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/186/)

Comment: Could you, please, explain what is "random open particles and others"? Or better, to illustrate what it is. As for now, your question is very hard to understand what you want in the result. Or you need to rework the question.

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks for the comment. i put my code.

Comment: looks like you try to repeat [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suqFV7VGsL4)

Comment: yes. exactly. Do you know the concept behind it ? and how to achieve it ?

Comment: have a look at the source code of this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_godrays.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [volumetric lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_lighting). Check this code example below or maybe better look at it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kkugej8/) (to see it in full dimensions not overplayed by console log).

It's based on [this](https://medium.com/@andrew_b_berg/volumetric-light-scattering-in-three-js-6e1850680a41) article. I slightly tweaked your code and updated the colors as well as some values and the code. It still needs some playing (e.g. number of faces, light color, shader properties etc.) but hopefully will help you. It all really depends how you wish to make it look like.

```js
THREE.VolumetericLightShader = {
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse: {value:null},
    lightPosition: {value: new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0.5)},
    exposure: {value: 0.18},
    decay: {value: 0.95},
    density: {value: 0.8},
    weight: {value: 0.4},
    samples: {value: 50}
  },

  vertexShader: [
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
      "vUv = uv;",
      "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
    "}"
  ].join("\n"),

  fragmentShader: [
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
    "uniform vec2 lightPosition;",
    "uniform float exposure;",
    "uniform float decay;",
    "uniform float density;",
    "uniform float weight;",
    "uniform int samples;",
    "const int MAX_SAMPLES = 100;",
    "void main()",
    "{",
      "vec2 texCoord = vUv;",
      "vec2 deltaTextCoord = texCoord - lightPosition;",
      "deltaTextCoord *= 1.0 / float(samples) * density;",
      "vec4 color = texture2D(tDiffuse, texCoord);",
      "float illuminationDecay = 1.0;",
      "for(int i=0; i < MAX_SAMPLES; i++)",
      "{",
        "if(i == samples){",
          "break;",
        "}",
        "texCoord -= deltaTextCoord;",
        "vec4 sample = texture2D(tDiffuse, texCoord);",
        "sample *= illuminationDecay * weight;",
        "color += sample;",
        "illuminationDecay *= decay;",
      "}",
      "gl_FragColor = color * exposure;",
    "}"
  ].join("\n")
};

THREE.AdditiveBlendingShader = {
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse: { value:null },
    tAdd: { value:null }
  },

  vertexShader: [
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
      "vUv = uv;",
      "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
    "}"
  ].join("\n"),

  fragmentShader: [
    "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
    "uniform sampler2D tAdd;",
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
      "vec4 color = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );",
      "vec4 add = texture2D( tAdd, vUv );",
      "gl_FragColor = color + add;",
    "}"
  ].join("\n")
};

THREE.PassThroughShader = {
 uniforms: {
  tDiffuse: { value: null }
 },

 vertexShader: [
  "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
    "vUv = uv;",
   "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
  "}"
 ].join( "\n" ),

 fragmentShader: [
    "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
   "gl_FragColor = texture2D( tDiffuse, vec2( vUv.x, vUv.y ) );",
  "}"
 ].join( "\n" )
};

(function(){
  var scene, camera, renderer, composer, box, pointLight,
      occlusionComposer, occlusionRenderTarget, occlusionBox, lightSphere,
      volumetericLightShaderUniforms,
      DEFAULT_LAYER = 0,
      OCCLUSION_LAYER = 1,
      renderScale = 0.5,
      angle = 0,
      sphere_mesh,
      mesh;
  
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );  
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  function setupScene(){
    var ambientLight,
        geometry,
        material;

    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x2c3e50);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    
    pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xddddff);
    scene.add(pointLight);
    
    geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 1, 32, 32 );
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x99ddff } );
    lightSphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    lightSphere.layers.set( OCCLUSION_LAYER );
    scene.add( lightSphere );
    
    camera.position.z = 6;
  }
  
  function addFragmentedSphere(){
    var geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry(2.9, 0);

  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    specular: 0xffffff,
    shininess: 1,
    flatShading: THREE.FlatShading,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: 1,
    wireframe:true

  });

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(mesh);

  //outer frame end

  //inner world like object start

  var sphere_material = [
      new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { transparent: true, opacity: 0 } )
  ];

  var sphere_geometry = new THREE.OctahedronGeometry( 2.7, 4 );
  // assign material to each face
  for( var i = 0; i < sphere_geometry.faces.length; i++ ) {
      sphere_geometry.faces[ i ].materialIndex = THREE.Math.randInt( 0, 1 );
  }

  sphere_geometry.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();

  sphere_mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere_geometry, sphere_material );
  sphere_mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0)
  mesh.add(sphere_mesh);
  sphere_mesh.layers.set( OCCLUSION_LAYER );
  }

  function setupPostprocessing(){
    var pass;
    
    occlusionRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth * renderScale, window.innerHeight * renderScale );
    occlusionComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, occlusionRenderTarget);
    occlusionComposer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
    pass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.VolumetericLightShader );
    pass.needsSwap = false;
    occlusionComposer.addPass( pass );
    
    volumetericLightShaderUniforms = pass.uniforms;
    volumetericLightShaderUniforms.exposure.value = 0.5;
    volumetericLightShaderUniforms.decay.value = 0.96;
    volumetericLightShaderUniforms.density.value = 0.95;
    volumetericLightShaderUniforms.weight.value = 0.59;
    volumetericLightShaderUniforms.samples.value = 100;
    
    composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
    composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
    pass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.AdditiveBlendingShader );
    pass.uniforms.tAdd.value = occlusionRenderTarget.texture;
    composer.addPass( pass );
    pass.renderToScreen = true;
  }
  
  function onFrame(){
    requestAnimationFrame( onFrame );
    update();
    render();
  }
  
  function update(){
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.003;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.003;
  }

  function render(){
    camera.layers.set(OCCLUSION_LAYER);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    occlusionComposer.render();
    
    camera.layers.set(DEFAULT_LAYER);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x090611);
    composer.render();
  }
  
  function addRenderTargetImage(){           
    var material,
        mesh,
        folder;

    material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( THREE.PassThroughShader );
    material.uniforms.tDiffuse.value = occlusionRenderTarget.texture;

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2 ), material );
    composer.passes[1].scene.add( mesh );
    mesh.visible = false;
  }
  
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', function(){

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    var pixelRatio = renderer.getPixelRatio(),
        newWidth  = Math.floor( window.innerWidth / pixelRatio ) || 1,
        newHeight = Math.floor( window.innerHeight / pixelRatio ) || 1;

    composer.setSize( newWidth, newHeight );
    occlusionComposer.setSize( newWidth * renderScale, newHeight * renderScale );
        
  }, false );
  
  setupScene();
  setupPostprocessing();
  addFragmentedSphere();//
  addRenderTargetImage();
  onFrame();
}())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/101/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://abberg.github.io/lib/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
<script src="https://abberg.github.io/lib/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
<script src="https://abberg.github.io/lib/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
<script src="https://abberg.github.io/lib/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
```

Comment: how can we adjust the params when adding background image to scene ?

Comment: @underscore Hi there. In my view the most relevant param is the color of rays (defined by the `pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xddddff);` line) and volumetric light properties (defined by `volumetericLightShaderUniforms` shader object inside the `setupPostprocessing()` function). Also perhaps the size of light sphere comparing to size of  `sphere_geometry`.

Comment: Do you have quick chat method ?

Comment: @underscore I can't see it.

Comment: after set `scene.background = texture;` . it will mess the background

Comment: @underscore Hmm.. background image can have potentially problems with custom shader. Did you try other methods of setting background image? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865537/three-js-set-background-image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158989/discussion-between-underscore-and-ivan-sivak).

Comment: @IvanSivak The snippet does not work anymore. Any chance of fixing this?

Comment: @CaptainObvious "Fixed". The problem was the version of threejs. My example included always up-to-date version of the library but since there have been some updates in the lib the example got broken. These changes came in threejs v.102. See the migration docs https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r101--r102 I tried to make it compatible with the newest threejs but the error keeps showing no matter what I tried and I don't have time to play with it now. I went back to 101 and it works now. Thanks for info.

Comment: @IvanSivak Thanks! It's ok like this I wanted to see visually what your code did.